# Find the conditional distribution of $X-4$ given $Y \geq 5$.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Let X be an exponential(1) random variable, and define Y to be the integer part of $X+1$, that is $Y=i+1$ if and only if $i \leq X < i+1, i=0,1,2,...$

Find the conditional distribution of $X-4$ given $Y \geq 5$.

My attempt: $Y \geq 5$ is equivalent $X \geq 4$. Thus $P(X-4 \leq x | Y \geq 5)=P(X-4 \leq x | X \geq 4) = \frac{P(4 \leq X \leq x+4)}{P(X \geq 4)} = 1-e^{-x}$

I don't know whether my answer is correct.

Comment: Your expression is only for $x \ge 0$ and you have a minor typo: $\frac{P(4 \leq X \leq X+4)}{P(X \geq 4)}$ should be $ \frac{P(4 \leq X \leq x+4)}{P(X \geq 4)}$

Comment: @Henry My idea is given $X \geq 4$, then the numerator has positive probability if $X-4 \geq 0$. So my support is $X \geq 4$

Comment: though you are looking at the conditional distribution of $X-4$ and have found $X-4\ge 0$

Comment: @Henry Yes. In other words, my expression is true if $x \geq 4 $. When $x < 4$, then the conditional pdf is 0.

Comment: No, not if $x$ is the value in $X-4 \le x$.  In that case your $1-e^{-x}$ is for $x \ge 0$

Comment: Suppose $x=-1$, then given $X \geq 4$, it is impossible that $X-4 \leq -1$. So the probability should be 0. However, if I plug $x=-1$ into $ 1- e^{-x}$, then I still give the positive probability 0.6321206.

Comment: If you plug $x=-1$ into $1-e^{-x}$ you get $1-e^{-(-1)}=1-e\approx -1.718$ which is not a probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct (although I assume you mean $\mathbb{P}(4\le\mathsf{X}\le x+4)$ in the numerator in your third expression) and it neatly shows a defining feature of the exponential distribution, namely that it is *memoryless*, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{X}\ge x+k\mid\mathsf{X}\ge k)=\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{X}\ge x)$, meaning that the conditional distribution of $\mathsf{X}-x$ given $\mathsf{X}\ge x$ is just the distribution of $\mathsf{X}$.

Comment: But what about the support (i.e., the range) of this distribution?

Comment: What you have found so far is the conditional CDF, so taking the derivative with respect to $x$ yields the conditional PDF. The support is exactly where this conditional PDF is positive, so you should find by the above, that the support at least includes $[0, \infty)$. What happens in the above if you plug in an $x<0$?

Comment: How to find $x \geq 0$?